# How to simplify $(\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) \cdot(\mathbf{B}\times \mathbf{C})?$

Tags: vector-analysis

We have $(\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) \cdot(\mathbf{B}\times \mathbf{C}).$ I have looked at a bunch of vectorial identites but none of them help me to simplify this one. Perhaps someone has more insight into this.

Comment: What do you want to semplify? it is simply the dot product of two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the determinant notation, and compute the scalar product. It doesn't seem to exist a simplification for that.

Eventually:

$$(\partial_y a_z - \partial_z a_y)(b_yc_z - b_zc_y) + (\partial_z a_x - \partial_x a_z)(b_zc_x - b_xc_z) + (\partial_x a_y - \partial_y a_x)(b_xc_y - b_yc_x)$$

Answer (score 0):

One needs to use Lagrange's Identity, thus we have: $$(\nabla \mathbf{B})(\mathbf{A\cdot C})-(\nabla \mathbf{C})(\mathbf{A\cdot B}).$$

Comment: You must have made some mistake somewhere: regardless of manipulations, it's the vector $A$ that is being differentiated, not the others.

Comment: Is $\nabla B$ supposed to mean $\nabla \cdot B$?  If so, I agree that the answer must be wrong: if  $B$ and $C$ are constant vectors, the expression in the answer always evaluates to $0$, whereas that is not necessarily the case for that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at $$\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_ja_k\varepsilon_{ilm} b_lc_m=\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}c_mb_l\partial_ja_k-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}c_mb_l\partial_ja_k=\\=c_kb_j\partial_ja_k-c_mb_l\partial_ma_l=((B\cdot\nabla) A)\cdot C-((C\cdot \nabla)A)\cdot B$$

Or, in more matrix-like form $$C^t(\nabla A)B- B^t(\nabla A)C$$